# Is there any way to create fixed stack size of Java Util stack

Tags: java, data-structures

I am creating a stck where I am using three cases. Case 1 is adding data, case 2 is poping and case three is printing.

When I enter choice 1 and adding some data, things is going fine. Now when I poping out I am getting

> java.util.EmptyStackException

. How to over come from that.

Things are working fine if I am creating Stack from other methods.

Here is my code.

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;

public class SolutionStack {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            int ch = sc.nextInt();
            stackMethod(ch);
        }

    }

    private static void stackMethod(int ch) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Stack st = new Stack();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        st.size();
        System.out.println(st.size());
        switch(ch){
        case 1: 
            int num = sc.nextInt();
            st.push(num);
            break;
        case 2: 
            st.pop();
            break;
        case 3 : 
            Iterator<Integer> iterator = st.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(iterator.next());
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: why don't you use [empty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html#empty()) to test first?

Comment: Please note that according to the Javadoc Deque should be preferred over Stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a Stack every time in the for loop.

Create Stack in the main function and pass in the method

```
Stack st = new Stack();
```

And this will be method signature.

```
private static void stackMethod(  Stack st, int ch)
```

The correct solution will be

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;

public class SolutionStack {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         Stack st = new Stack();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            int ch = sc.nextInt();
            stackMethod(st,ch);
        }

    }

    private static void stackMethod(Stack st, int ch ) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        st.size();
        System.out.println(st.size());
        switch(ch){
        case 1: 
            int num = sc.nextInt();
            st.push(num);
            break;
        case 2: 
            st.pop();
            break;
        case 3 : 
            Iterator<Integer> iterator = st.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(iterator.next());
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This code is solving my issue but I am still confused about Stack size: Let me do some work around this

Answer (score 0):

Your `stack` is a local variable in the method `stackMethod`, so for every call a new stack object will be created.

Make `st` as a class variable and it should work:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;
public class SolutionStack {

    Stack st = new Stack();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            int ch = sc.nextInt();
            stackMethod(ch);
        }

    }

    private static void stackMethod(int ch) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        st.size();
        System.out.println(st.size());
        switch(ch){
        case 1: 
            int num = sc.nextInt();
            st.push(num);
            break;
        case 2: 
            st.pop();
            break;
        case 3 : 
            Iterator<Integer> iterator = st.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(iterator.next());
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I am confused by this code.  If the OP at `int ch = sc.nextInt();` enters `2` then in `stackMethod` the code would be `st.pop()` but as the Stack would be empty, the same error will occur - unless the OP ensures that `1` is entered before `2` then a check for `empty` is still required - no?